# Is it possible to use a traditional MQ (RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ) in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, activemq-classic, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a Java webapp (running in Tomcat) that uses ActiveMQ to queue up "jobs" in response to actions that a user takes.

I'm considering porting the application to Google App Engine and I know they offer a Task Queue API but I would prefer to stick with a messaging/queuing system that's a little less container-specific, like JMS or AMPQ.

I am wondering if it's possible to start an instance of a messaging server like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ inside of GAE.  Or does that idea not make sense in a distributed environment like GAE?  I'm still just looking into GAE so the distributed nature of it is a bit of a mystery to me at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't start ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ inside of GAE, you might be able to run it elsewhere and connect using the experimental socket connections, but I doubt that it would be worth it.

It's probably a better solution to write some kind of abstraction that uses Task Queue API with GAE and other solutions elsewhere if you're worried about lock in.

Comment: That seems like the best way to go.  Things are pretty well abstracted already so I guess I'll just be writing new Task Queue implementations and updating my Spring configuration.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You cant use ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ in GAE. If you don't have any preference of Cloud Hosting,  you can configure try Active/RabbitMQ inside **Amazon EC2**.

Article that discuss about this can be found in this [link](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ec2.html).

Update: now you can use [Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute/) and install your rabbitMQ/ActiveMQ there.

Comment: I guess I would rather stick with GAE but thanks for the info on EC2.  I've been trying to keep my application as container-neutral as possible so that might still be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use RabbitMQ in GAE now: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/rabbitmq/

Comment: Google App Engine and Google Cloud Platform are actually 2 different products.
GCP is a full VM solution much like Amazons EC2.

Comment: Google App Engine and Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine is 2 different product.